# Sign in Preprocessing Number

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, standards, c++14

In Section 2.10 in the C++ Standard 14 ([lex.ppnumber]), preprocessing numbers are defined as

```
pp-number
    digit
    . digit
    pp-number digit
    pp-number ' digit
    pp-number ' nondigit
    pp-number identifier-nondigit
    pp-number e sign
    pp-number E sign
    pp-number .
```

So this should include all integer literal tokens and all floating literal tokens. But as  written in 2.14.4 ([lex.fcon]), there a sign is optional i.e. (if there is a way to format it as in the standard, feel free to improve).

```
exponent-part:
    e sign_opt digit-sequence
    E sign_opt digit-sequence
sign: one of
    + -
```

Why is the sign in the pp-number definition not optional? In fact the way it is written, the number 1e3 should be valid as floating-literal, but not as a pp-number, which contradicts the explanation given below section 2.10.

Is there something I do not get?

Comment: `1E3` is a valid pp-number. `E` uses the identifier-nondigit production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html):

> **A preprocessing number has a rather bizarre definition.** The category includes all the normal integer and floating point constants
>   one expects of C, but also a number of other things one might not
>   initially recognize as a number. Formally, preprocessing numbers begin
>   with an optional period, a required decimal digit, and then continue
>   with any sequence of letters, digits, underscores, periods, and
>   exponents. Exponents are the two-character sequences ‘e+’, ‘e-’, ‘E+’,
>   ‘E-’, ‘p+’, ‘p-’, ‘P+’, and ‘P-’. (The exponents that begin with ‘p’
>   or ‘P’ are new to C99. They are used for hexadecimal floating-point
>   constants.)
>
> **The purpose of this unusual definition is to isolate the preprocessor from the full complexity of numeric constants.** It does
>   not have to distinguish between lexically valid and invalid
>   floating-point numbers, which is complicated. The definition also
>   permits you to split an identifier at any position and get exactly two
>   tokens, which can then be pasted back together with the ‘##’ operator.
>
> It's possible for preprocessing numbers to cause programs to be
>   misinterpreted. For example, 0xE+12 is a preprocessing number which
>   does not translate to any valid numeric constant, therefore a syntax
>   error. It does not mean 0xE + 12, which is what you might have
>   intended.

Answer (score -1):

The number "1e3" is, in fact, a valid preprocssing number. You're not reading what the grammar implies correctly. A digit, followed by an identifier non-digit (that is a letter, in this case "e"), followed by a digit, does indeed conform to the grammar.