# Why does this simple code not consistently compile?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, c++14, clang++

The following code compiles on g++, clang, and Visual Studio:

```
#define HEX(hex_)  0x##hex_
int main()
{
    return HEX(BadC0de);
}
```

as does this modification, using C++14 digit separators:

```
    return HEX(1'Bad'C0de);
```

But this won't compile on g++ or clang (it works on Visual Studio):

```
#define HEX(hex_)  0x##hex_
int main()
{
    return HEX(A'Bad'C0de);
}
```

g++ output:

```
<source>:4:1: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    4 |     return HEX(A'Bad'C0de);
      | ^  
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:4:17: error: expected ';' before user-defined character literal
    4 |     return HEX(A'Bad'C0de);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:1:25: note: in definition of macro 'HEX'
    1 | #define HEX(hex_)   0x##hex_
      |                         ^~~~
<source>:4:17: error: unable to find character literal operator 'operator""C0de' with 'int' argument
    4 |     return HEX(A'Bad'C0de);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:1:25: note: in definition of macro 'HEX'
    1 | #define HEX(hex_)   0x##hex_
      |                         ^~~~
```

**UPDATE: interestingly, the preprocessor output for this is**

```
    return 0xA'Bad'C0de;
```

**which *does* compile, so obviously the standalone preprocessor is working differently here than the unified preprocessor.**

This also fails on g++/clang, but with different errors:

```
    return HEX(Bad'C0de);
```

g++ output:

```
<source>:4:19: warning: missing terminating ' character
    4 |     return HEX(Bad'C0de);
      |                   ^
<source>:5:2: error: unterminated argument list invoking macro "HEX"
    5 | }
      |  ^
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:4:12: error: 'HEX' was not declared in this scope
    4 |     return HEX(Bad'C0de);
      |            ^~~
<source>:4:15: error: expected ';' at end of input
    4 |     return HEX(Bad'C0de);
      |               ^
      |               ;
<source>:4:15: error: expected '}' at end of input
<source>:3:1: note: to match this '{'
    3 | {
      | ^
```

**Update: preprocessor stops before parsing the HEX() argument in this case.**

I'd like to believe this is a g++ bug, but given how badly noncompliant Visual Studio's preprocessor has historically been, perhaps that is wishful thinking. And in fact, that last program not only fails on g++, it **also** triggers an internal compiler error on Visual Studio (at least on godbolt.org)!

msvc output:

```
<source>(4): error C2001: newline in constant
<source>(4): fatal error C1057: unexpected end of file in macro expansion
Internal Compiler Error in Z:\opt\compiler-explorer\windows\19.00.24210\bin\amd64\cl.exe.  You will be prompted to send an error report to Microsoft later.
INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'Z:\opt\compiler-explorer\windows\19.00.24210\bin\amd64\cl.exe'
    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```

Naively, I would have expected all the compilers to just pass all text to the macro substitution before trying to interpret its meaning (it is a PRE-processor after all!); only after the ## concatenation would I expect the token to be examined for meaning. (Yes I know that some basic parsing happens to match parenthesis, brackets, etc. so that commas within them don't split arguments, but I would not expect that to extend to any other language constructs.)

Does the standard have anything to say about these programs? Are they somehow non-conformant, or are they legal and the compilers are buggy?

Comment: If you stop after preprocessing, and looked at the preprocessed (but not compiled) source, does it look alright to you? Can you please [edit] your question to include the preprocessed source as well?

Comment: When compiling with gcc, did you specify the language standard to use?

Comment: @Chris Yes, -std=c++14.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added some preprocessor reference points. These actually make me lean more toward "compiler bugs", but there again the output is not consistent.

Comment: "it works on Visual Studio" [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/W3zhYjbdK).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I don't actually have a Visual Studio install locally, I used godbolt.org for that (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xso9ovn4Y).

Comment: Your code snippet shows the `#` operator but your actual code has `##`. Please use copy and paste function, don't re-type code in the question.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Sorry, I actually did use copy and paste, but at one point I was fiddling with string-ification to see if it made a difference, and presumably didn't get the text completely fixed back up before I copied it.

Comment: Anyway, `/Zc:preprocessor` uses the new conforming preprocessor. MS documentation says "off by default, except in C11/C17" but that appears to be a lie. It is always off by default. Enable it explicitly.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Interesting, the MSVC++ version I was using apparently doesn't know about the /Zc:preprocessor option anyway, so that answers the question about whether Visual Studio was following the standard when it compiled the code: clearly it was still using the badly non-conformant preprocessor (what Microsoft euphemistically calls their "traditional" preprocessor, I guess because they traditionally don't follow standards?).

Comment: That's weird. If you use `-E` to get the pre-processor output from gcc, that compiles fine. But if you compile the code, that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of those nasty holes in the spec.  The preprocessor is defined (in the spec) in terms of "preprocessing tokens".  The input is first split into a sequence of preprocessing tokens and then macro processing happens on that sequence.

Now the problem comes from the fact that `0xA'Bad'C0de` is a single preprocessing token, but `A'Bad'C0de` is not -- it is three preprocssing tokens (`A`, `'Bad'`, and `C0de`) and the token paste operator `##` is defined to just paste two adjacent tokens.  In this case the tokenization phase depends on what macros have been defined and what they might do.

Fixing this would require non-trivial spec changes, and require tracking directly-adjacent preprocessing tokens vs non-directly-adjacent tokens (those that have whitespace or comments between them) and having the `##` operator potentially paste additional directly-adjacent tokens when that makes sense.

This would still have problems with things like `HEX(A'B)` -- how would you tell when the `)` should be part of a multichar character constant token vs ending the macro argument list?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that g++ was wrong to compile "return HEX(1'Bad'C0de);" then"?

Comment: It's not clear to me if the spec requires a diagnostic for that, or if it falls under the heading of Undefined Behavior where the compiler is permitted to accept it as an extension.

Comment: Re: "how would you tell when the ) should be part of a multichar character constant token vs ending the macro argument list?" -- Well, *I* wouldn't directly support multichar character constants in macros, just like templates aren't directly supported in macros (e.g. commas in template parameters aren't treated like commas within parenthesis; instead, they act as argument delimiters, which is often surprising but at least keeps macro processing simpler).
Anyway, I've never understood the use of (implementation-defined) multichar constants (as distinct from the well-defined, UTF-8 constants).

Answer (score 2):

The *preprocessing tokens* notably includes [*preprocessing numbers*](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ppnumber#nt:pp-number), which are a superset of regular numeric literals.

`1'Bad'C0de` is a valid preprocessing number. It begins with a decimal digit, and conforms to the grammar of *pp-number*. Thus it is treated as a whole by `##`.

`A'Bad'C0de`, on the other hand, is not a preprocessing number, since it doesn't begin with a digit.

This quirk is implemented correctly in g++ and clang, as well as MSVC's new preprocessor (which can be enabled with [`/Zc:preprocessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-preprocessor?view=msvc-170)). MSVC's traditional preprocessor is based on character buffers, rather than preprocessing tokens, which is non-conforming.

Comment: Nice, the terminology you mentioned here gave me the search terms to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32942611/11398236), which clarifies that "The category includes all the normal integer and floating point constants one expects of C, but also a number of other things one might not initially recognize as a number... to isolate the preprocessor from the full complexity of numeric constants". This explains why any alphanumeric sequence is accepted after ```1'B``` (whereas normal numeric tokenizing would have noticed that's not a valid numeric literal).